# website with virtual directory

Tags: iis-7, iis, virtual-directory

I have a website running which is using asp.net and iis 7.

I made some changes to the website and I wanted to do some testing using the same url but in a sub directory like /private/test

So in IIS I set up a virtual directory inside the main application pointing to the code with the changes. Then I converted it to an application.

But I get iis errors like

> "the entry in web.config testDataconnection has already been added."

How would I fix this so I could get this running?

**abc123.com** main asp.net application is here

**abc123.com/private/test** test application is here -this is just a clone of the original with a few modifications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your configuration file after the `<providers>` and before the first `<add....>` node add a  node. that will fix it.

For more [information](http://forums.asp.net/p/1017928/1372020.aspx)